# Win32 - How to get input from specific windows class?

Tags: c++, class, winapi

I am using this windows class as an input box for my choose player name window http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13330/Using-Dialog-Templates-to-create-an-InputBox-in-C --I read the entire description provided with the codeproject submission but none of it describes how I can actually output the input from the box. Can anyone tell me how I can do this? For example, user inputs name 'bob'. Message box appears says "hey user your name is " ...

`GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(..., ...), storage_var, 16);`

How can I fill in these parameters assuming that is how you would get input using this windows class? What values would I put in there, how would this work? All help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

This is how I am calling it:

```
char buf[256] = " ";
                            WIN32INPUTBOX_PARAM param;
                            param.szTitle = "[RESOURCE] PING!";
                            param.szPrompt = "PONG!";
                            param.szResult = buf;
                            param.nResultSize = MAX_PATH;
                            param.DlgTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(101);
                            CWin32InputBox::InputBoxEx(&param);
                            CWin32InputBox::InputBox("Testing", "enter detail"
                                                               , buf, 256, true);
```

Following that how would i get input into a variable from that input box?

Comment: If you're using that code the `InputBox` function takes a parameter to return the input in.

Comment: but when I output that parameter in a `MessageBox` for testing purposes it doesn't show up, and its just a blank box.

Comment: please also provide some code of where this is being called -- maybe from a window proc? how is the window proc defined and how is this code called from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RetiredNinja mentioned in his comment, you need to use the parameter, like

```
char buf[100] = "";
CWin32InputBox::InputBox("hello", "what?", buf, 100, false);
MessageBox(hDlg, buf, "You entered this", MB_OK);
```

**EDIT**

The code above is for a "straight" Win-API without MFC.
If you are using MFC, (please edit the question and add the [mfc](/questions/tagged/mfc) tag), the code would look like:

```
char buf[100] = "";
CWin32InputBox::InputBox("hello", "what?", buf, 100, false);
MessageBox(buf, "You entered this", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Makes sense but in the case of hDlg where does HWND assign a variable in this class?

Comment: It's defined as a private variable in the structure, how can I access it beyond this?

Comment: I'm not using mfc, but when I put hDlg into that box then it says `"hDlg" is undefined`

win32inputbox.cpp and win32inputbox.h are both in my project file respectively in their contained folders.

Comment: if you are not using MFC, you'll need to use the first part of the answer, `hDlg` is the handle to your dialog box (or your main window if you are not using a dialog box)

Comment: As I said, I'm using this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13330/Using-Dialog-Templates-to-create-an-InputBox-in-C 

How would I do it with that class? What is the HWND variable there?

Comment: that's just the class to get the input -- edit your question and give some code of how you are calling the class and where the function is being called from